# Google Compute Engine Health Check with Basic Auth

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am trying to do a Google Compute Engine Health Check for a service that I've deployed. However, I have a Firewall in place and Basic Auth restricting access.

Do I need to open up my Firewall so that Google's servers can do the health check? Also, is there any way to include the authorization header so that the request goes through or should I turn off Basic Auth for the health check URL?

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking about the GCLB health check then yes, you'll need to allow Google's load balancer to access your service. In general, connectivity is required for any types of health check and you need to make sure that the health check communication channel is open between the health check client and the server whose health is being checked.

In particular, if you are talking about Load Balancing, currently according to its documentation, only the HTTP method is supported and the return HTTP status code must be 200 to indicate a successful check.

Comment: Yes, I am talking about GCLB health check. So are you saying that I would need open the Firewall to the IP address associated with the forwarding rule?